# Listview item in android should show name of ble device but should hide MAC address of device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am been trying to find a way to display Ble devices in an android application. I want to show only the name of the Ble device but want to hide the MAC address of the device.

currrently my code for gets the list of ble devices and displays a string of name and MAC address. On selection from the listview, the string containing the ble deivce name and MAC is sent an another activity where the MAC is used to connect to the device

```
String macadd = result.getDevice().getAddress();
String bt_name = result.getDevice().getName();
// check if device is already added to list
if(!device_mac_list.contains(macadd)){
   device_mac_list.add(macadd);
//  adds name and mac to new ble device to list
   devicelist.add("Device Name:" + bt_name + "\n" + "MAC:" + macadd);
   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

ListView declaration

```
private ListView bt_devices;
ArrayList<String> devicelist = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DevActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, devicelist);
bt_devices.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I want to only display the name of the device and keep the mac address hidden in the list view. the rest of the process will be the same

Thank You

Comment: Cleaton, can you post more code to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is storing the name and the mac address of the device in a Map as a key-value format.

Code for storing the key-value pair in map is

```
HashMap<String, String> filterDevices = new HashMap<>();
if(!device_mac_list.contains(btMac)){
    device_mac_list.add(btMac);
//  storing bluetooth device name in map with device name and mac address in key value pair
    filterDevices.put(btName, btMac);
    devicelist.add("Device: "+btName);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The MAC address can be retrieved from the map using the name received from selection of list view

```
bt_devices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String deviceName = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
        String deviceMac = filterDevices.get(deviceName);
        Log.d("select", deviceName+":"+deviceMac);
    }
});
```